# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'eventListenerHooks' of undefined jqplot.highlighter.min.js:4

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jqplot

Hello I have a problem in my php code and javascript! The problem is 
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'eventListenerHooks' of undefined jqplot.highlighter.min.js:4"

I don't know why I take that error. The line in the javascript that has the problem is:

```
d.jqplot.eventListenerHooks.push(["jqplotMouseMove", f]);"
```

and writes

> Cannot read property 'eventListenerHooks' of undefined

The code of my jqplot is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var tips = [<?php 
        if (!empty($scheduledTips)) {
            foreach ($scheduledTips as $value) {
                echo "['" . $value->date . "'," . $value->tips . '],';
            }
        } else {
            echo '["No_tips",0]';
            } 
        ?>];
       var quizzes = [<?php
        if (!empty($scheduledQuizzes)) {
            foreach ($scheduledQuizzes as $value) {
            echo "['" . $value->date . "'," . $value->quizzes . '],';}
        } else {
            echo '["No_Quizzes",0]';
            } 
        ?>];
       var commitments =[ <?php
        if (!empty($scheduledCommitments)) {
            foreach ($scheduledCommitments as $value) {
                echo "['". $value->date . "'," . $value->commitments . '],';
            }
        } else {
            echo '["No_Commitments",0]';
            } 
        ?>];  

        var plot1 = $.jqplot('ScheduledTips', [tips,quizzes,commitments], {
            title: 'Actions',seriesColors: ['#00749F','#7bc523','#e87511','#00ffd2','#6b4423','#c7bebe','#847847', '#153115', '#FF0000', '#F0A804', '#800080','#000000','#fc9758',
            '#4c3d00','#800080','#4c393c','#000099','4c4c4c','#122a11','52c6c5','#112a2a','#6c8e3b'],
            animate: true,
        // Will animate plot on calls to plot1.replot({resetAxes:true})
        animateReplot: true,
                 legend:{
            show:true, 
            location: 'e',
            rendererOptions:{numberRows: 3, placement: 'outside'}
        },
        cursor: {
            show: true,
            zoom: true,
            looseZoom: true,
            showTooltip: false
        },
            series: [{pointLabels: {
                    show: false
                },rendererOptions: {

                    // Speed up the animation a little bit.
                    // This is a number of milliseconds.  
                    // Default for bar series is 3000.  
                    lineWidth:4,    
                    animation: {
                        speed: 2500
                    },
                    varyBarColor: true,
                    barWidth: 20,
                    barPadding: -15,
                    barMargin: 0,
                    highlightMouseOver: true
                }}], series: [ {label: "Tips"},{label: "Quizzes"},{label: "Commitments"}],
            grid: {
                drawGridLines: true, // wether to draw lines across the grid or not.
                gridLineColor: '#cccccc', // CSS color spec of the grid lines.
                background: 'white', // CSS color spec for background color of grid.
                borderColor: '#999999', // CSS color spec for border around grid.
                borderWidth: 2.0, // pixel width of border around grid.
                shadow: true, // draw a shadow for grid.
                shadowAngle: 45, // angle of the shadow.  Clockwise from x axis.
                shadowOffset: 1.5, // offset from the line of the shadow.
                shadowWidth: 3, // width of the stroke for the shadow.
                shadowDepth: 3
            },
      axes:{
      yaxis: { pad: 1.05,min:0} ,
        xaxis:{
          renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer, 
                 pad: 1.05,
                  tickOptions: {
                        showGridline: false
                    }
        }
      }, 
            highlighter: {
                show: true,tooltipLocation: 'n',
                tooltipContentEditor : tooltip,
                sizeAdjust: 18.5}
  });
    });
```

And the code for html is:

```
if (!empty($stats)) {
            echo '<div class="col-md-12"><div id="ScheduledTips" style="height:400px;width:700px;margin-left:00px;padding-bottom:20px"></div></div><br/>';
        }
```

I have all the js libraries loaded. But I have from the start of the page that problem! Anyone knows how to fix it?

Comment: what is the sequence of files when you load them. make sure you load the main jqplot.js file first and then all the other jqplot files..

Comment: I found the mistake!!!! It was as you said wrong load of the files! and also one same file twice!!!!!